# Determine if an array of PSCustomObject's contains an instance with a property value

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, pester

I need to determine if an array of `PSCustomObject`s contains an item with its `Title` property matching a value. I need a Boolean value for use with [Pester](https://github.com/pester/Pester) assertions:

```
$Items -<function> $Name | Should Be $True
```

Assuming:

```
$Items = @()
$Items += [PsCustomObject]@{Title='foo';Url='http://f.io'}
$Items += [PsCustomObject]@{Title='bar';Url='http://b.io'}
```

`Contains` does not work:

```
PS> $Items -contains 'foo'
False
```

`Match` returns the matching instance, but it is not a Boolean:

```
PS> $Items -match 'foo'

Title  Url
-----  ---
foo    http://f.io
```

I suppose I could:

```
($Items -Match $Name).Count | Should Be 1
```

Is there a better option?

Comment: @craig for match: `[bool]($Items -match 'foo')`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use:

```
$Items.Title -contains 'foo'
```

Comment: Is there any way to check $items Property like if Title exists or not ?

Comment: To check if the property exists; the way I have found is to enumerate them. `$getResult | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select -ExpandProperty Name` and look for the result `($Items| Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -contains 'Title' as seen in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2